# Android ExpandableListView about arrays

Tags: android

I'm planning to add expandablelistview in my activity. I did some researches on the Internet but none of them fits what I want. I read also that expandablelistview has parent and child elements. What I want to do is that the parent would be the categories let's say it's fruits, then its children are Apple, Lemon, Almonds, etc. I'd like to try that by using arrays, but am not so familiar with List and Hash.. Please give me some snippets of codes to start with.. appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Expandable List View is quite easy to implement. You can just easily create two arrays with items that you want to add in the list. For more details and insight into the intricacies of the Expandable ListView you can take a look at this link:
[Simple Expandable ListView Example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/)

Also, if you need to create a Custom Expandable ListView, then you can find a good tutorial for that on this link:
[Custom Expandable ListView](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/)